# Calculating a definite (a to b) integral in t-domain using the Laplace transform of the integrand

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have a question regarding the Laplace transforms.

Suppose $F(s)=L$ {$f(t)$}. Can we calculate a definite integral like $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt$ by an integratin (or any operation) on $F(s)$ in the s-domain?
I know the answer for the special case $\int_{0}^{t}f(t)dt=L^{-1}${$\frac{F(s)}{s}$}.
But, I want $a$ and $b$ to be arbitrary constants.
Parseval's theorem is also useless for this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "calculating an integral in the s-domain"? The Laplace transform is a priori defined for functions of one real variable (say $f(t)$). What is the variable in $\int_a^b f$?

Comment: Suppose that we have F(s) at hand. We want to calculate $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt $ by  the knowledge of F(s) only. We do not want to invert F(s). Are there any theorems for this?

Comment: Try searching up the convolution property/formula of Laplace transform. I dont know if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: @user758469   I know about the convolution property and that is not what I am looking for. Let me give you an example. Can we calculate $ \int_{1}^{2} t dt$  by only having $L${$t$}$=\frac{1}{s^2}$. I am looking for a way to do some operations in the s-domain only, to calcualte the integral.

Comment: @HoomanFatoorehchi: you can always obtain an expression for $\int_1^2 f(t) dt$ depending only on $F(s)$ using the integral expression of $f(t)$ as a function of $F$ (but it's probably not going to be extremely nice)

Comment: @md5 Thanks. Can you elaborate? Do you mean by inverting F(s)? I do not want to invert F(s).